# Equivalent of mpif90 --showme for Cray Fortran Wrapper ftn

Tags: fortran, wrapper, cray

I am currently compiling code on a HPC system that was set up by Cray. To call Fortran, C, and C++ compilers it is suggested to use `ftn`, `cc`, and `CC` compiler wrappers provided by Cray.

Now, I would like to know which options the `ftn` wrapper adds to the actual compiler call (in my case to `ifort`, but it should not matter). From working with MPI wrappers I know the option `--showme` to get this information:

```
> mpif90 --showme
pgf90 -I/opt/openmpi/pgi/ib/include -fast -I/opt/openmpi/pgi/ib/lib -L/opt/openmpi/pgi/ib/lib -lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77 -lmpi -libverbs -lrt -lnsl -lutil -ldl -lm -lrt -lnsl -lutil
## example from another HPC system; MPI wrapper around Portland Fortran Group Compiler
```

I am locking for an option like `--OPTION_TO_GET_APPENDED_FLAGS` that provides the same information for the `ftn` wrapper

```
> ftn --OPTION_TO_GET_APPENDED_FLAGS
ifort -one_option -O2 -another_option
```

Because it is Friday afternoon local time all colleagues with knowledge on this topic left already for their weekend (as well as the cluster support team).

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: With the cray system I have access to I can do `ftn --craype-print-opts=all` to get a lot of this information, although perhaps not everything. It may be worth a go at least.

Comment: @d_1999 Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, this option is not recognized at our system.

Comment: I did not read the manual properly. The command at our Cray system is `-craype-verbose`.

Answer (score 1):

On the Cray system I am using (Cray Linux Environment (CLE), 27th Apr. 2016), the appropriate option is `-craype-verbose`:

```
ftp -craype-verbose
> ifort -xCORE-AVX2 -static -D__CRAYXC [...]
```

It is written on the man page which I just scanned quickly before asking this question:

```
-craype-verbose
      Print the command which is forwarded to compiler invocation.
```